# How to get a summary of Posts by month? i.e. month with count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get a list of months that contain Posts in the Post table, along with the count of posts for the month.

e.g.

```
JAN 11
FEB 23
MAR 4
```

So some months won't show up if there are no posts for that month.

My post model is like:

```
Post (ID, TITLE, DATE_CREATED)
```

I don't need the actual posts returned, just the MONTH and the COUNT for the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way probably (rails2 not sure about 3 but should be similar):

```
Post.count(:group=>'MONTH(DATE_CREATED)')
```